# Is it possible to use spatial autocorrelation test to determine the tuning parameter in the thin plate spline smoother?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, spatial, smoothing

I am currently working with some insurance data and try to estimate spatial structure of claims frequencies. The common approach is to perform some kind of regression on the non-spatial data then smooth the residuals as they incorporate both random and spatial effects (to be precise to smooth function of spatial coordinates $Y: R^2 \rightarrow R$ ) The question is: how much to smooth to get rid of as much randomness as possible.
The $\lambda$ parameter in thin plate spline smoother determine how much smooth is the estimated surface.

My thesis advisor suggested me to try out some tests for spatial autocorrelation as the method of estimating $\lambda$. What he meant was: smooth until a test statistic reaches critical value. Claims frequencies normally would demonstrate some positive autocorrelation, my intuition is that smoothing would only produce even more significant autocorrelation. This is also the case with my data - p-value of Moran's I test converges to zero when $\lambda$ grows. Is there any way to use autocorrelation tests as sort of estimator for $\lambda$?

I am not searching for any other way of estimating $\lambda$ just need to judge on this "method".